# Pgsql UPDATE in a web system with multiple entities

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, postgresql, inline

I want to update ta.nmbr and ta.totl to an existing indctr. How do I do it? is it possible to join?

This is the SELECT query.

```
$sql = "SELECT ind.indctr_code, ind.indctr_name, ctr_ind.ctr_indctr_id, ta.actl_trgt, ta.nmbr, ta.totl 
    FROM indctr AS ind 
    LEFT JOIN ctr_indctr 
    AS ctr_ind ON ind.indctr_code = ctr_ind.indctr_code 
    LEFT JOIN actl_trgt AS ta 
    ON ctr_ind.ctr_indctr_id = ta.ctr_indctr_id
    LEFT JOIN qtr
    ON ta.qtr_code = qtr.qtr_code";
```

[This is the ralationship of the entities.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PhQOO.png)

I was doing an inline editing table for this where the indctr_code and the indctr_name are already there. and the data for ta.nmbr & ta.totl will be editable in the table.

Comment: `update ta.nmbr and ta.totl to an existing indctr`. Which values are going into the updated columns *exactly*?

Comment: nmbr = 90, totl = 100, where actl_trgt = 1

Answer (score 1):

A plain [`UPDATE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html):

```sql
UPDATE actl_trgt
SET    nmbr = 90
     , totl = 100
WHERE  actl_trgt = 1;
```